# RewriteEngine to hide extension and HTTPS redirect in httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have read multiple posts about RewriteEngine and I believe my case is unique.

I have full access to my own server and I have the following lines added in my httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

HTTPS redirect works. Hiding PHP file extension DOES NOT.
Is there some conflict going on here? Or is everything is correct and I need to look at my httpd.conf configuration?

Apache version: 2.2.15
Everything is up-to-date and mod-rewrite and mod-ssl are installed. For security reasons .htaccess file is disabled on my system.

Comment: can you show some examples of `uri`s in that situation?

Comment: Can't you just use [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews)? Does the same thing without the hassle

Comment: @yoda - http://mydomain.com/test - produces error, when I am trying to access test.php

Comment: @Phil, no I have not. Let me look into that

Comment: Not to discourage you, but maybe it would be better to proxy all php requests through index.php? That way it's easier to mask php extension.

Comment: I have finally solved it. Here is a solution to those who struggled: Make sure that in httpd.conf `Options + FollowSymLinks` for the directory that you want to enable the option (usually web root). Now, within the same <Directory> block or right under the Options +FollowSymLinks ,add 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`. Put HTTP redirect code `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}' into <Virtual Host> if any. This is a solution without using .htaccess